# In terraform, how to filter a json with null values

Tags: filter, terraform, databricks

I have a terraform variable, which is a json as follows:

```
{
  a: "A",
  b: "",
  c: "C",
  d: "",
  e: "E",
  f: "F"
}
```

I need to use only the key and value where value is NOT null

I tried the following but it did not work

```
resource "databricks_secret" "workspace" {
    for_each        = [for key, value in local.workspace_vars: { k: key, v: value} if value != null]
    key             = each.value.k
    string_value    = each.value.v
}
```

How to go about this?

I want the json to be as follows to be usable:

```
{
  a: "A",
  c: "C",
  e: "E",
  f: "F"
}
```

Comment: Were there any errors? If so, add them to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with

```
resource "databricks_secret" "workspace" {
    for_each        = toset([for key, value in local.workspace_vars: key if value != null])
    key             = each.key
    string_value    = each.value
}
```